# MYSQL : How to insert multiple value in a single column using array and only if not exist

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a site where I want to add songs with all details like `Artist` ,`Label` etc. I upload song using `addfile.php` file. This page have individual text input fields and form POST to `addfile_db.php` where I have some `SQL` Query. 
Query for insert into file. Works ok. Dont want any changes.

```
 $qryUpdate = "insert into file
 (name,artist,music,label,lyrics, recommended,dname,cid,ext,thumbext,size,`desc`,newtag,date,imagetype) 
VALUES 
 ('$name','$artist','$music','$label','$lyrics','$recommended','$newname',$cid,'$ext','$thumbext','$fileSize','$des','$newtag','(now())',0)";
$db->query($qryUpdate);
```

I also want to insert `$artist` value into `artist` table. A single song may multiple artist. `$artist` have comma seperated value like this  `Artist1,Artist2,Artist3` and I explode values into array.

```
$artist_array = explode(","$artist);
```

I try this query.

```
   $ArtQry = "insert  into artist (name) VALUES ('" . implode("'), ('", $artist_array) . "')";
  $db->query($ArtQry);
```

Above codes works perfectly. Adds 3 rows to table `artist` with unique id lke 1,2,3,4 ....

Problem is this that I want to insert into `artist` if already not exist.
I have tried this code but not works, inserts nothing when I use these code.

```
INSERT INTO artist (name)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '" . implode("', '", $artist_array) . "') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT name FROM artist WHERE name = '" . implode("'), ('", $artist_array) . "')";
) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: you posted this already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165142/explode-array-and-insert-into-table-if-not-exist

Comment: But not getting solution from anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSERT IGNORE` or `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=name` assuming `name` is a UNIQUE key.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

...but enough about that...

If you want to create a proper, [First Normal Form (1NF)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/first-normal-form.htm) then never doom your database with columns that hold comma-separated values.

As a specific example, let's say you want to INSERT an artist called "*Does It Offend You, Yeah?*" or "*What Price, Wonderland?*"

Uh oh, you are going to be exploding/imploding in php and JOINing ON IN/LOCATE/FIND_IN_SET in mysql based solely on those delimiting commas resulting in unwanted surgery on artist names(*no delimiter is safe with all the funky artist name possibilities), but things get worse...

What about two or more [bands that have the same name](http://rateyourmusic.com/list/noname219/popular_artists_with_the_exact_same_name/)!  You don't have any means to differentiate them.

If you have any shred of interest in future-proofing your data, you will need to expand your database design with sufficient separate tables to avoid CSVs.

If you don't, you are going to find yourself doing some unreliable and slow-performing queries using FIND_IN_SET and other workarounds that could have been fully avoided if you had invested your early development time setting up a healthy set of tables, each with unique primary keys.

If this is coming off sounding too judgmental, I apologize.  You should find some solace in the fact that developers big and small are prolifically building database tables with CSVs -- some out of ignorance, some out of habit, some think it is more efficient, and on and on.

Some SO members may chime in to say that each case is different and developers must choose what is best for their specific agenda, but for your case I have already listed two different varieties of conflict.

Truth told, in my earlier days I inherited some CSV tables and had to learn how to hack and workaround them.  In my ignorance, I copied what I saw and set up CSVs in my future DB builds until someone (or some site) enlightened me; and now I can't see myself ever going back.

Comment: Thanks. Now, I'm running my site as I wanted. Can you please check that http://djpunjab.com does same as I'm doing.

Comment: @Yogi I wouldn't have a clue where or how to begin testing your site.  If my answer has solved your problem please award it the green tick (and possibly an upvote for being helpful) so that this question is removed from the "unanswered" list.  Good luck